# Setting an overlay background panel on a dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

Right, so I'm drawing what looks like a DataGrid on a standard WPF Grid panel.

The content controls are essentially TextBlock controls inside Border controls at Grid row and column references to create the overall layout, added at runtime and using the usual Grid.SetRow() and Grid.SetColumn() methods

Not every X and Y grid reference has a content control - this is determined by a runtime definition of the data for the grid. I use offset values to mark whether an XY pair is part of the "headers" of the rows/columns or whether the grid reference is part of the "data" section.

I am trying to put a gradient background across the whole of the "data" section. I was using a Grid control with the gradient brush set as follows:

```
//Grey background to show for "grey cells"
Grid greyBackground = new Grid()
{
     Background = (Brush)this.Resources["BackgroundBrush"],
     VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
     HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
     Width = double.NaN,
     Height = double.NaN,
};
greyBackground.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
greyBackground.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

Grid.SetColumn(greyBackground, _vm.Definition.ColumnOffset);
Grid.SetRow(greyBackground, _vm.Definition.RowOffset);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(greyBackground, _vm.Definition.Columns - _vm.Definition.ColumnOffset);
Grid.SetRowSpan(greyBackground, _vm.Definition.Rows - _vm.Definition.RowOffset);
cellGrid.Children.Add(greyBackground);
```

This however is not visible at all. And I have no idea why.

Any idea how I can display a gradient background painted control over these row/column locations, underneath the other "data" controls?

Comment: @HighCore, I'm not saying I disagree with you, but your comment isn't very helpful.  Could you maybe explain to OP why this is a bad idea, or offer an alternate method?

Comment: @Stewbob that would be too long for a comment, and will require me to post an answer. I'm hesitant about that because it will not be an answer to the question as-is. Therefore I might get downvotes.

Comment: @Stewbob but, if you want me to mention an alternate method, I will say what I say to everybody else: **Learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF.**

Comment: @HighCore That's hardy a helpful suggestion i'm afraid (can you learn to walk before/without trying it?)... Anyway to the OP: that's just so wrong...

Comment: @StefanDenchev that's clearly an exaggeration on my part. I'm the most exaggerated person in the history of mankind.

Comment: @Highcore & Stewbob: Okay, obviously missing the original comment but I can guess... In this case, I don't think MVVM can actually help with this without overcomplicating the Model. Bear in mind because this is a completely custom rendering due to presentation logic requirements and handling the input interface (mouse clicks, keyboard state). This seemed the easiest option and overall the code is clean. You also are not seeing the fact that "_vm" is an interface, not a concrete class (yes, I have read the blogs even tho' I'm breaking pattern).